# Joining decendent text nodes of XML/HTML in Xpath

Tags: python, xml, xpath, scrapy

I have this html fragment:

```
<tr>
    <th scope="row" style="text-align:left;">Appeared in</th>
    <td class="" style="">1972<sup id="cite_ref-dottcl_2_2-0" class="reference"><a href="#cite_note-dottcl_2-2"><span>[</span>2<span>]</span></a></sup></td>
</tr>
<tr>
    <th scope="row" style="text-align:left;">Usual 
<a href="/wiki/Filename_extension" title="Filename extension">filename extensions</a>
    </th>
    <td class="" style="">.h .c</td>

</tr>
```

I am using `//th//text()` expression to parse it.

The problem is it's returning `['Appeared in', 'Usual', 'filename extensions']`.

What I want is `['Appeared in', 'Usual filename extensions']`.

Comment: Not possible in PHP with common extensions, so I removed the tag. A PHP xpath 1.0 variant is: http://eval.in/32515 - But it's not really xpath.

Comment: This will mainly be used in scrapy. But first I experiment with a tool written in PHP.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need XPath 2.0 for doing this which is not supported by most XML-libraries of those scripting languages (including scrapy).

If you can use a more capable XPath processor (also have a look at XQuery 1.0 and newer, they all include at least XPath 2.0 as a subset), use:

```
//th/data()
```

`/data()` is equivalent to `/data(.)` which calls the function for the current context.

### `data()` vs `text()`

While `text()` is not a function call, but node filter (and thus `//text()` is an axis step adding all text nodes individually to the result sequence), `data()` is a function aggregating all data for the current context (here: each `<th/>` individually).

### XPath 1.0 limitations

There is no way to call any function that concatenates strings for each table header element individually: Function calls in axis steps are not supported, nor are explicit loops like they're possible in XPath 2.0.

Comment: Shouldn't `//th/data(//text())` work? though Its not working.

Comment: Function calls in axis steps are not support in XPath 1.0, XPath 2.0 introduced them. I will edit my answer in a few minutes to explain this more detailed. And you'd need to call `//th/data(.//text())` or you'd return all text nodes starting from the root for each table header, surely not what you'd want to do. :)

Comment: @JensErat: Are you sure that `data(...)` is in xpath 1.0? I tried to look that up in the specs but could not find it.

Comment: Aye you're right, there is no data function. Fixed that, either way the argumentation on looping stays valid.

Answer (score 0):

Ah I will get downvoted for parsing HTML with [regex](/questions/tagged/regex), but can't be helped:

```
$html = '<tr>
    <th scope="row" style="text-align:left;">Appeared in</th>
    <td class="" style="">1972<sup id="cite_ref-dottcl_2_2-0" class="reference"><a href="#cite_note-dottcl_2-2"><span>[</span>2<span>]</span></a></sup></td>
</tr>
<tr>
    <th scope="row" style="text-align:left;">Usual 
<a href="/wiki/Filename_extension" title="Filename extension">filename extensions</a>
    </th>
    <td class="" style="">.h .c</td>

</tr>';

$html = str_replace("\r", '', str_replace("\n", '', $html)); // Remove new lines
preg_match_all('#<th[^>]*>(.*?)</th>#is', $html, $m); // Match what's between th tag

$result = array_map('strip_tags', $m[1]); // Get ride of html tags
print_r($result);// printing the results
```

**Output:**

```
Array
(
    [0] => Appeared in
    [1] => Usual filename extensions    
)
```

Comment: You only get DV because OP asks for Xpath.

Comment: Sure, you could also do: `if ($input === 'string in question')  return ['Appeared in', 'Usual filename extensions']; return [];` because the HTML was given in the question as well ^^